# Gson “fromJson”

Tags: java, gson

Gson.fromJson(“some/url/path”, String.class) throws `MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON`. Why gson treating url string as Json when it is not while Gson.fromJson(“simpleString”, String.class) works fine. Shouldn’t it treat url as string too?

Comment: I would recommend single stepping through the code in the debugger to see exactly what's causing the exception - perhaps they take different codepaths / overloads?

Comment: I'm surprised that `simpleString` isn't treated as malformed. It should be invalid according to the [docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html).

Comment: What makes you think the string argument is treated like a URL? The documentation of [`fromJson(String, Class)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class)) very clearly specifies that the **string value is the JSON text itself**. Since `some/url/path` isn't valid JSON, of course it gets rejected!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples are wrong, but Gson makes some simple guesses.

If your JSON Object is a String, it should be quoted.

```
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("\"http://some/string\"", String.class));
```

works fine.

If the JSON String is not quoted, it will work only with a single alphanumeric sequence, even a slash will break Gson's guesses about the type.